# Seeing full result in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I wrote:

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

dcut2 <- diamonds %.%
  group_by(cut,clarity,color) %.%
  summarize(
    meancarat=mean(carat,na.rm=TRUE),
    ndiamonds=length(carat)
  )

dcut2
```

The output is:

```
Source: local data frame [276 x 5]
Groups: cut, clarity

    cut clarity color meancarat ndiamonds
1  Fair      I1     D 1.8775000         4
2  Fair      I1     E 0.9688889         9
3  Fair      I1     F 1.0234286        35
4  Fair      I1     G 1.2264151        53
5  Fair      I1     H 1.4986538        52
6  Fair      I1     I 1.3229412        34
7  Fair      I1     J 1.9934783        23
8  Fair     SI2     D 1.0169643        56
9  Fair     SI2     E 1.0156410        78
10 Fair     SI2     F 1.0801124        89
..  ...     ...   ...       ...       ...
```

Note that I did not use the tbl_df tool. Why is is cutting off the rest of the output? How can I see the rest of the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default print-out is only 10 rows, which I think most would agree is a good thing to avoid cluttering the console.

Try

```
  dcut2 %.% head(276)
```

to print your full df to the console..

In RStudio, you can also do

```
 View(dcut2)
```

to view the data in the spreadsheet viewer..

Comment: Or `dcut2 %>% View` ;)

Answer (score 1):

reconvert to data.frame

```
data.frame(dcut2)
```

there you go